# Changing the value of the variable from another shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I have a shell script that has a on/off switch inside. I programmed the Housekeeping.sh to execute this certain line of code if the value is at 1 and don't execute it if it's at 0.
The following is the code on my Housekeeping.sh:

```
ARCHIVE_SWITCH=1
if [[ $ARCHIVE_SWITCH -eq 1 ]]; then
    sqlplus ${BPS_SCHEMA}/${DB_PASSWORD}@${ORACLE_SID} @${BATCH_HOME}/sql/switch_archive.sql
fi
```

Now I want to create another shell script file that I'll execute to automatically change the variable `ARCHIVE_SWITCH`equals to 0 everytime I execute this script.
Is there any other way that I can change the value of the variable `ARCHIVE_SWITCH` from another shell script file that I'll execute manually?

Comment: You will need to `export` the `ARCHIVE_SWITCH` variable from the **parent** shell of each of the two scripts you want to have access to the variable. Generally either create a wrapper script that exports the variables and then starts each shell script in the background, or you can export in your `.bashrc` and have any script make use of it. (**rule** a *child process* may never change the environment of its *parent* -- so you need the *parent* to make the environment variable available)

Comment: ... Or, you can create a function or alias which sets the variable in your current shell, or create a script file which you manually `source` from that shell.

Comment: In any event, probably remove the assignment from the housekeeping script, or change it to one which supplies a default value but does not override the variable if it is already set.

Comment: Change `ARCHIVE_SWITCH=1` to `: ${ARCHIVE_SWITCH=1}`.  If it's not set in the environment, it will be set to 1.  If it is already set in the environment, this will be a no-op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an option to the script:

```bash
bash housekeeping.sh      # default is off
bash housekeeping.sh -a   # archive switch is on
```

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

archive_switch=0

while getopts :a opt; do
    case $opt
        a) archive_switch=1 ;;
        *) echo "unknown option -$opt" >&2 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if ((archive_switch)); then
    sqlplus ...
fi
```